# Как создать active для разных компонентов?

Tags: массивы, reactjs, jsx, state

Есть компонент ItemsList:

```
import React from 'react'

const ItemsList = ({items}) => {

  return (
    <ul className="items">
      {items.map(({comment}, index) => (
         <li 
            key={index} 
            className="item"
            >{comment}
         </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default ItemsList
```

Использую я его так:

```
const Viem = () => {

  const obj = {
    test1: [
      {comment: 1},
      {comment: 2}
    ],
    test2: [
      {comment: 1},
      {comment: 2},
      {comment: 3}
    ]
  }

  return (
    <div className="content">
      <ItemsList items={obj.test1} />
      <ItemsList items={obj.test2} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Я хочу сделать возможность кликать по **item** и добавлять им класс **active**.

Но, как мы видим, у нас компонент один, а передается два разных объекта и нужно что-бы у каждого был свой **active**.

Как это правильно сделать?

> Для тех, кто не понял о чем я написал: скажем у нас есть киносайт, у него есть сериал и при просмотре сериала у нас есть возможность сменить серию или сезон. Использовать я хочу redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Создадим компонент отображения списка, с возможностью выбрать один элемент(сделать его активным, установив нужный класс)

Создаем в компоненте **ItemsList** переменную состояния **active**, в которой будет находится индекс выбранного элемента массива(по умолчанию -1).

При клике на элемент списка, будем записывать индекс в состояние и при рендере проверять, если индексы совпали, то ставим данному элементу класс активного.

Если кликнули на тот же элемент, то класс активного будет снят(если это не надо, то заменить сеттер на `setActive(index)`)

```
const ItemsList = ({items}) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(-1);
  
  return (
    <ul className="items">
      {items.map(({comment}, index) => (
        <li
          key={index}
          className={active === index ? 'activeItem' : 'item'}
          onClick={() => setActive(index !== active ? index : -1)}
        >{comment}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Если надо, что бы у каждого li было свое собственное состояние, то декомпозируем компонент ItemsList на 2

```
const Item = ({ comment }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <li
      className={active ? 'activeItem' : 'item'}
      onClick={() => setActive(a => !a)}
    >{comment}
    </li>
  )
}

const ItemsList = ({items}) => {

  return (
    <ul className="items">
      {items.map(({comment}, index) => <Item comment={comment} key={index} />
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Теперь у каждого элемента есть свое состояние и клик по нему ставит или убирает класс активного.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Кхм... У меня это варинт проходил и даже работал но я почему-то думал, что он будет работать только для одного компонента :)

Comment: Теперь понял, что это как создать 2 одинаковых обьекта, но свойства у них будут разные :)

Comment: А не дополните пожалуйста ответ?) Можете пожалуйста показать как из одного компонента отправить get запрос, достать данные и передать в redux и в другом компоненте их показать после клика на кнопку с откуда отправляется get запрос? Буду благодарен))))

Comment: @user569536 оформите это отдельным вопросом. Что за компоненты, как связаны(если связаны), что хотите сделать и что не получается.

Comment: угу! щас создам